# Reducing INDSET and MAXCUT to 3SAT

Tags: np-complete, reductions, satisfiability, np, max-cut

Given a graph and an integer $k$ is there an independent set larger than $k$ is INDSET problem and is there a cut larger that $k$ is the MAXCUT problem. Is there standard way to convert to 3SAT from these problems that preserves number of solutions? I have only seen reductions other way in standard texts. Since all these are NPC there should be a way to convert back.

Comment: The standard way is known as the Cook-Levin theorem, and it preserves the number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{INDSET}$ $\leq_p$ $\mathcal{3SAT}$:

For each vertex $v\in V$, create a Boolean variable $x_v$.

For each edge $uv\in E$, create a clause $\lnot x_u \lor \lnot x_v$

Now, to assure that there exist exactly (or more than) $k$ variables assigned to $\mathrm{TRUE}$, we need to sum over all the assigned value ($\mathrm{FALSE}$ as $0$, $\mathrm{TRUE}$ as $1$):

We use [half-adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder) and [full-adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder). Note that each circuit gate using some Boolean operation like $C = A \oplus B$ can be transformed into $\mathcal{3SAT}$ clauses easily.

To compare the obtained sum and $k$, it is straightforward from their binary representations (as two arrays of Boolean variables), just scan from left to right (in big-endianness fashion).

$\mathcal{MAX-CUT}$ $\leq_p$ $\mathcal{3SAT}$:

For each vertex $v\in V$, create a Boolean variable $s_v$. A cut is then described by a partition of the vertex set $V=S\cup (V\setminus S)$, where $v\in S$ iff. $s_v=\mathrm{TRUE}$.

For each edge $e=uv\in E$, create a Boolean variable $c_e$ and some clauses to force that $c_e=(s_u\neq s_v)$. So, $c_e=\mathrm{TRUE}$ iff. $e$ is crossing $(S, V\setminus S)$.

Then, we use half-adder and full-adder as before to count the number of crossing edges. Lastly, compare as before.